# Can I download a large file in byte range in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, http, nsurlsession

I have 60 MB of file and I want to download this file in part by part from 2 or more separate threads. Would it be possible to download file from byte range option from each thread separately.

Here are the data which I am getting from server in response.

```
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
Age = 46330;
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 1001;
"Content-Range" = "bytes 0-1000/6116016";
"Last-Modified" = "Wed, 30 Nov 2016 10:55:52 GMT";
"X-Cache" = "Hit from cloudfront";
```

Like for thread one :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString* range = @"bytes=";
range = [range stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] stringValue]];
range = [range stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
range = [range stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000] stringValue]];

[request setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
```

For thread 2 :

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString* range = @"bytes=";
    range = [range stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000] stringValue]];
    range = [range stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
    range = [range stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:2000] stringValue]];

    [request setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
```

Comment: Did you try your above code? faced any issue?

Comment: It's not downloading what I am expecting the data. It only downloading of 1001 byte every time.

Comment: ok... you are getting only the first 1001 bytes everytime? how did you verify that?

Comment: check this answer.. your server should support Range header.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452522/resume-download-functionality-in-nsurlconnection